# how to calculate the probability of winning using rigged dice

Tags: probability

You are proposed to play the following game of dare. You have $5$ dice with these characteristics, three faces are black, two faces are blue and the remaining face is red. If you get at least two red faces, you win $30$; if you get at least four blue faces, you win $20$; while, in other cases, you lose $5$. Calculate the payout average in this game.

My attempt:

I tried using binomial giving each case its own success rate for example the red case, would be $$(x \geq 2) = \binom{5}{2}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^2\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^3 + \binom{5}{3}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^3\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^2$$ and so on until $\binom{5}{5}$ and did that for all $3$ cases, but the values I got added up to more than $1$, and also I dont actually think thats what is used to get it solved.

Comment: Please tell us what you have attempted and where you are stuck.

Comment: well, i tried using binomial giving each case its own success rate for example the red case, would be (x>=2)= 5ncr2 [(1/6)^2]x[(5/6)^3] + 5ncr3 [(1/6)^3]x[(5/6)^2] and so on until 5ncr5 and did that for all 3 cases, but the values i got added up to more than 1 and also i dont actually think thats what is used to get it solved

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a reference and tutorial for typesetting math on this site. (It's very hard to read otherwise.) Please also see [How to ask a good question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: It sounds like you had the right approach.  I recommend double-checking your calculations, and making your blue case is set up as well as your red case.  Instead of trying to count (all other cases), which is much harder than the other two,  I would just use $(1-p)$ where $p$ is the total probability of winning (or if you want the number of losing cases, use **_total cases_** - **_winning cases_**).  If you do that, you're probabilities can't possibly add up to more than 1.

Answer (score 1):

$P(X=30)=\sum\limits_{n=2}^{5}\binom5n\cdot\left(\frac16\right)^{n}\cdot\left(1-\frac16\right)^{5-n}=\frac{763}{3888}$

---

$P(X=20)=\sum\limits_{n=4}^{5}\binom5n\cdot\left(\frac26\right)^{n}\cdot\left(1-\frac26\right)^{5-n}=\frac{176}{3888}$

---

$P(X=-5)=1-P(X=30)-P(X=20)=\frac{2949}{3888}$

---

$E(X)=30\cdot\frac{763}{3888}+20\cdot\frac{176}{3888}-5\cdot\frac{2949}{3888}=\frac{11665}{3888}\approx3$